# How to fix drop down list not passing value in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I made a creation form and within it a dropdown list dynamically populated by elements from a table in my database, problem is the dropdown list selected item doesn't pass its value to the controller and a validation alert keeps showing up saying that it's the dropdown list is a required field (considering it not selected), i removed the validation tag and i get an SQL error stating that my dropdown list is passing null (non-nullable field in my db), this is the html fragment for the dropdown list

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('interventions.store') }}">
      <div class="form-group">
          @csrf
          <label for="name">Type Intervention:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="type">
              <?php
              $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestionpreventionincendie', 'root', '');
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM type_intervs";
              $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
              $stmt->execute();
              $types = $stmt->fetchAll();
               foreach($types as $type): ?>
              <option value="<?= $type['id']; ?>">
              <?= $type['type']; ?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select><br/>
          <label for="com">Commentaire:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="commentaire"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmer</button>
  </form>
```

this is store method in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([

]);
$user = Auth::user();
$intervention = new Intervention([
  'type' => $request->get('type'),
  'commentaire' => $request->get('commentaire'),
  'user' => $user['email']
]);

$intervention->save();
return redirect('/interventions')->with('success', 'Intervention Ajouté');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a name for your options

```
 <select class="form-control" name="type">
              <?php
              $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestionpreventionincendie', 'root', '');
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM type_intervs";
              $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
              $stmt->execute();
              $types = $stmt->fetchAll();
               foreach($types as $type): ?>
              <option name="type" value="<?= $type['id']; ?>">
              <?= $type['type']; ?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select><br/>
```